# How can I determine how many staking nodes are run by an operator?

Tags: stake-pool

When selecting a Cardano Stake Pool for delegation, I have been relying on taking a look at their website and making a judgement call about whether they are are a sole operator with a single node.

Is there a way to determine if that is true or a good source that lists the stake pool operators by number of nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't by the protocol. You're depending on each node being honest. This is because from the protocol perspective each pool is independent that a single owner owns. That being said, there are a few things you can check that are reported by the pool operator when they register the pool that can indicate related nodes.

1. Pool metadata. A lot of operations list same or similar metadata for each of their pools, for example 1PCT does this
2. Pool registered relays. You can be fairly certain that multiple pools using the same relay addresses registered by the pool are probably the same operator.
3. Pool rewards address. If multiple pools are sending their rewards to the same address, that would indicate they're owned by the same operator.

Comment: Additionally, you can take a look at the Cardano Single Pool Alliance here: https://singlepoolalliance.net/